# Where, in the U.S.A, deucravacitinib is given?

Tags: psoriasis

deucravacitinib is a novel oral therapy for Psoriasis, [it was approved on September 9, 2022 by the FDA](https://www.psoriasis.org/advance/fda-approves-sotyktu-for-psoriasis/#:%7E:text=%22Deucravacitinib%20is%20a%20once%2Ddaily,central%20to%20what%20causes%20psoriasis.). It is still very new and there is no full data about side effects, but how could general practitioners or even dermatologists from another country (outside the U.S.A) could know where in the U.S.A it is given to refer their patients?

For example, which hospital/s in the U.S.A already started to administer this medicine?

Comment: Drugs.com has a complete monograph on it so I would imagine a doctor who treats psoriasis would be aware of it and would know where to find information. It doesn't appear to me to be a drug used only in hospitals, so I don't think that would be what to look for. Any doctor who cares to know should be able to find all the information they need just like I did.

Comment: Hello @CareyGregoryisonstrike, does the information you refer to available only to doctors of medicine? Because for me, as someone who is curious and looks from the side, in https://www.drugs.com/mtm/deucravacitinib.html no data about whereabouts is available.

Comment: If my understanding of US medicine is correct, it's a question of if you can pay for a treatment or your health insurance covers it being a deciding factor next to clinical considerations. Being new and nich, it's unlikely to be available free. But you can check with the WHO if it's on their list of essential medications, which should be freely available.

Comment: I would expect a doctor can simply write a prescription, give it to a pharmacy, and they would be able to obtain the drug. Drugs aren't restricted to certain geographic areas in the US and I don't see any indication it's rare or difficult to obtain. It is, however, very expensive ($6500 for 30 tablets).